# Cannot Install Sci-Kit Learn Package on Mac OSX Error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip

I am running the latest Python version 3.6.4.

I install pip via these instructions from https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

> To install pip, securely download get-pip.py. [1]:
>
> curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
>
> Inspect get-pip.py for any malevolence. Then run the following:
>
> python get-pip.py
>
> pip install -U pip

Finally when I get to install SciKit Learn here is what I ran into:

> pip install -U scikit-learn
>
> > Collecting scikit-learn
> >       Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/scikit-learn/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) - skipping
> >
> > Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scikit-learn (from versions: )
> >     No matching distribution found for scikit-learn

I couldn't find anything on stackover specifically addresing my problem and tried some suggested solution without success. (i.e. pip uninstall scikit-learn, sudo pip install scikit-learn)

I am really stumped here on why I cannot install scikit learn package. I want to start using it. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, this was a temporary issue with the cert. I just loaded it (using a 3.6.5 virtual environment with pip 10.0.0) and had no issues. I also loaded https://pypi.python.org/simple/scikit-learn/ into Opera and the cert is definitely valid now.

I would also suggest using a virtualenv  (https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/). It avoids some frustrating issues like pip pointing to the 2.7 version instead of pip3.

Comment: I still have this issue. Should I uninstall Python and reinstall it?

Can I get it working without using a virtual env as an extra step?

Comment: The virtualenv is definitely optional, it just removes some possible scenarios when more than one Python is installed into the OSX /Libraries and also manages dependencies if you have more than one active Python project going.  If you have 2.7 and 3.6 installed, you might run _pip --version_ and be sure you are using the correct one or just always use _pip3_ to be sure.

Comment: When I ran pip 8.1.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7) it says: 

> pip 8.1.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

But I deleted Python 2.7 and installed Python 3.6.4 (the latest version) so I should only have that. Why is it saying I have Python 2.7 and how do I remove it completely?

Comment: Python on MAC follows Apples rules. That's why I really prefer the virtualenv path.  One you're in the soup, the only real answer is to remove all Python and start over following the MAC guides. 

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/